# Does $I(a,b)=\frac{a}{b+1}I(a-1,b+1)$?

Tags: integration

If $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^bdx$, where $a \geq 1, b \geq 1$, does $I(a,b)=\frac{a}{b+1}I(a-1,b+1)$ for $a \geq 2$? I've tried numbers like $a=2, b=2$, and it seems to be true so far. Any proof that this is true?

Comment: Integration by parts. I’d honestly be interested in knowing if you tried and found where it led.

Comment: @Aruralreader I did exactly that! Let $u=x^a$ and $dv=(1-x)^bdx$ and went from there. Someone answered below that this is apparently false. So I guess I must have messed up somewhere.

Comment: Oh -- wait a second; my proof is technically not a proof; because I made a silly error in one of the steps. The identity is actually true; and you do have to just do integration by parts. I will go ahead edit the answer. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: @ArunBharadwaj: best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer had a silly calculation error that I had made; the identity is in fact true.

As suggested in the comments, we proceed with integration by parts.

$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b dx = \left[\frac{-x^a(1-x)^{b+1}}{b+1}\right]_0^1 + \int_0^1\frac{ax^{a-1}(1-x)^b}{b+1}dx$$ $$= 0 + \frac{a}{b+1}\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b+1} = \frac{a}{b+1}I(a-1, b+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^b\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b+1)}{\Gamma (a+b+2)}$$
$$I(a-1,b+1)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b+1}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b+2)}{\Gamma (a+b+2)}$$
$$\frac{I(a,b) } {I(a-1,b+1)}=\frac{a}{b+1}$$ just as you wrote.